# NextJS Image parameter issue

Tags: next.js

We are using NextJs image for loading images and its working fine.

But we have a situation of image url generation like below

```
https://example.com/_next/image?url=/static/icons/Callus.svg&amp;w=48&amp;q=75
```

Here the image is not loading because of this & instead of just &.

So any work around to solve it inside NextJs ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the link `https://example.com/_next/image?url=/static/icons/Callus.svg`, without the `&` and adjust the settings in the `Image` component.